# PySipp: Getting an attribute error in Pycharm and a ModuleNotRecognized error in Terminal when trying to run PySipp

Tags: python, sipp, pysipp

I am trying to run PySipp on my MacBook and am getting two different errors just by writing a simple line of code from PySipp. In terminal, I have tried starting up both Python 2 and Python 3 and get a ModuleNotFound error just by importing PySipp. In PyCharm, I am able to import it without any issue; however, I run into issues when running anything. Using a simple print command will make the item print twice. When I try to run the sample PySipp command in the docs: 
import pysipp
pysipp.client(destaddr=('10.10.8.88', 5060))()
gives me a "AttributeError: module 'pysipp' has no attribute 'client'" error. Interestingly (just a side note), my print statement only runs once before getting the error instead of twice.

I've install and uninstalled PySipp through Pip through the provided code in the docs: pip install git+git://github.com/SIPp/pysipp.git

I have also downloaded the files through GitHub as a zip and opened them. Other than that, I have tried in different python projects and in Pycharm and Terminal and read the docs like 5 times through.

Because terminal doesn't recognize the module, I am not sure if it is an installation error or a file location error.

```py
# the code that does not work in PyCharm
# here are the docs: https://github.com/SIPp/pysipp
import pysipp
pysipp.client(destaddr=('10.10.8.88', 5060))()
```

```py
# the code that does not work in Terminal
import pysipp
```

I expected the program to run successfully. In Pycharm, here was my complete error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   line 1, in 
>       import pysipp
>   line 2, in 
>       pysipp.client(destaddr=('10.10.8.88', 5060))()
>   AttributeError: module 'pysipp' has no attribute 'client'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Error in terminal: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysipp'

Answer (score 0):

try to install following and retry

pip install git+https://github.com/SIPp/pysipp.git